# Optimal data structure (in C++) for random access and looping through elements

Tags: c++, data-structures

I have the following problem: I have a set of N elements (N being somewhere between several hundred and several thousand elements, let's say between 500 and 3000 elements). Out of these elements, small percentage will have some property "X", but the elements "gain" and "lose" this property in a semi-random fashion; so if I store them all in an array, and assign 1 to elements with property X, and zero otherwise, this array of N elements will have n 1's and the N-n zeros (n being small in the 20-50 range).

The problem is the following: these elements change very frequently in a semi-random way (meaning that any element can flip from 0 to 1 and vice versa, but the process that controls that is somewhat stable, so the total number "n" fluctuates a bit, but is reasonably stable in the 20-50 range); and I frequently need all the "X" elements of the set (in other words, indices of the array where value of the array is 1), to perform some task on them.

One simple and slow way to achieve this is to simply loop through the array and if index k has value 1, perform the task, but this is kinda slow because well over 95% of all the elements have value 1. The solution would be to put all the 1s into a different structure (with n elements) and then loop through that structure, instead of looping through all N elements. The question is what's the best structure to use?

Elements will flip from 0 to 1 and vice versa randomly (from several different threads), so there's no order there of any sort (time when element flipped from 0 to 1 is has nothing to do with time it will flip back), and when I loop through them (from another thread), I do not need to loop in any particular order (in other words, I just need to get them all, but it's nor relevant in which order).

Any suggestions what would be the optimal structure for this? "std::map" comes to mind, but since the keys of std::map are sorted (and I don't need that feature), the questions is if there is anything faster?

EDIT: To clarify, the array example is just one (slow) way to solve the problem. The essence of the problem is that out of one big set "S" with "N" elements, there is a continuously changing subset "s" of "n" elements (with n much smaller then N), and I need to loop though that set "s". Speed is of essence, both for adding/removing elements to "s", and for looping through them. So while suggestions like having 2 arrays and moving elements between them would be fast from iteration perspective, adding and removing elements to an array would be prohibitively slow. It sounds like some hash-based approach like std::set would work reasonably fast on both iteration and addition/removal fronts, the question is is there something better than that? Reading the documentation on "unordered_map" and "unordered_set" doesn't really clarify how much faster addition/removal of elements is relative to std::map and std::set, nor how much slower the iteration through them would be. Another thing to keep in mind is that I don't need a generic solution that works best in all cases, I need one that works best when N is in the 500-3000 range, and n is in the 20-50 range. Finally, the speed is really of essence; there are plenty slow ways of doing it, so I'm looking for the fastest way.

Comment: Sounds like a good usecase for a [disjoint set](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disjoint-set_data_structure). There is an implementation of [`disjoint_sets`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_64_0/libs/disjoint_sets/disjoint_sets.html) in `boost`.

Comment: Why would the loop be slow?

Comment: @CoryKramer I'm not sure I see how you'd use a disjoint set here, since those data structures typically don't support "find all objects in this class" and don't support splitting classes. Perhaps I'm missing something?

Comment: I highly doubt iterating over a 3000 elements in a `std::vector` is a bottleneck. Have you measured this to be an actual problem?

Comment: Use two arrays (one for X, and one for non-X)? Move an element from one to the other when X-ness changes. When moving, put the last element of the array to the empty place.

Comment: @bolov I could see that being an issue if it's done pretty frequently, which it seems like would be the case based on what the OP is describing.

Comment: "because well over 95% of all the elements have value 1" you mean 0, don't you?

Comment: `unordered_map` and `unordered_set` aren't appropriate here unless you use a pair of them, because you can't iterate through just the subset you need. Insertion/deletion for the unordered versions are O(1) while the regular versions are O(log n). Iteration through any of them will be substantially slower than iterating through an array.

Comment: "adding and removing elements to an array would be prohibitively slow". Are you sure that you understand Mark's answer? Or my comment above? That's not slow at all, it's an O(1) operation. That's the fastest solution you can get.

Comment: @geza : yes, you are correct, I meant "because well over 95% of all the elements have value 0"

Comment: @geza `push_back` to `std::vector` is O(1) amortized, although it can be O(n) for any single insert worst case. But removal is always O(n) unless the element is at the end.

Comment: @MarkRansom: I didn't meant `std::vector`'s remove. In my previous comment I wrote: "When moving, put the last element of the array to the empty place". It's an O(1) operation.

Comment: @geza I realize that's not what *you* were talking about, but I suspect it's what *Bojan* was talking about. It's important to not talk past each other.

Answer (score 4):

Since order doesn't appear to be important, you can use a single array and keep the elements with property X at the front. You will also need an index or iterator to the point in the array that is the transition from X set to unset.

- To set X, increment the index/iterator and swap that element with the one you want to change.
- To unset X, do the opposite: decrement the index/iterator and swap that element with the one you want to change.

Naturally with multiple threads you will need some sort of mutex to protect the array and index.

Edit: to keep a half-open range as iterators are normally used, you should reverse the order of the operations above: swap, *then* increment/decrement. If you keep an index instead of an iterator then the index does double duty as the count of the number of X.

Comment: Thank you Mark. I think I understand what you are saying; by swapping the desired element with the n-th one, I avoid having to copy part of an array upon deletion, but doesn't it still take in average n/2 operations to find that element that I need to swap (since they are not sorted)?

Comment: @Bojan your question didn't say anything about how you selected elements to set to `X`. If you need to do a linear search then yes, it could potentially be n/2 on average. If this is an important consideration then it should have been included in the question; the more constraints you put into the question, the better.

Comment: you need a linear search into the vector to swap elements if you don't have them sorted in any way. And keeping the non-flagged elements unsorted as well would force you to do such search on them every time too

Answer (score 1):

`N=3000` isn't really much. If you use a single bit for each of them, you have a structure smaller than 400 bytes. You can use `std::bitset` for that. If you use an `unordered_set` or a `set` however be mindful that you'll spend many more bytes for each of the `n` elements in your list: if you just allocate a pointer for each element in a 64bit architecture you'll use at least 8*50 = 400 bytes, much more than the bitset

Comment: about performance: the smaller and more compact your data structure is, the faster the algorithm, because most of the time spent in traversing data structure is cache miss.

Comment: Yes, but I still have to loop through all the bits, so I still need to do 3000 operations (compare if bit is 1 or 0) to get all the 1s; am I missing something here?

Comment: yeah but 3000 cheap operation is likely to have better performance than 50 expensive operation. In particular on my laptop looping all the bits takes 1.5µs

Comment: moreover, if you are in a multi-thread environment where one thread is updating the bitset and another is looping through the bits you may not need to lock the structure (and even if you want to synchronize some writes, you may copy the whole structure before looping on it asynchronously). You may need to re-implement the bitset in order to have an atomic read-modify-write `set` operation if you want to write to it with more than one thread.

Answer (score 0):

@geza : perhaps I misunderstood what you meant by two arrays; I assume you meant something like have one std::vector (or something similar) in which I store all elements with property X, and another where I store the rest? In reality, I don't care about others, so I really need one array. Adding an element is obviously simple if I can just add it to the end of the array; now, correct me if I'm wrong here, but finding an element in that array is O(n) operation (since the array is unsorted), and then removing it from the array again requires shifting all the elements by one place, so this in average requires n/2 operations. If I use linked list instead of vector, then deleting an element is faster, but finding it still takes O(n). That's what I meant when I said it would be prohibitively slow; if I misunderstood you, please do clarify.

It sounds like std::unordered_set or std::unordered_map would be fastest in adding/deleting elements, since it's O(1) to find an element, but it's unclear to me how fast can one loop through all the keys; the documentation clearly states that iteration through keys of std::unordered_map is slower then iteration through keys of std::map, but it's not quantified in any way just how slow is "slower", and how fast is "faster".

And finally, to repeat one more time, I'm not interested in general solution, I'm interested in one for small "n". So if for example I have two solutions, one that's k_1*log(n), and second that's k_2*n^2, first one might be faster in principle (and for large n), but if k_1 >> k_2 (let's say for example k_1 = 1000 and k_2=2 and n=20), second one can still be faster for relatively small "n" (1000*log(20) is still larger than 2*20^2). So even if addition/deletion in std::unordered_map might be done in constant time O(1), for small "n" it still matters if that constant time is 1 nanosecond or 1 microsecond or 1 millisecond. So I'm really looking for suggestions that work best for small "n", not for in the asymptotic limit of large "n".

Comment: You misuse this site, don't add comments as answers. You haven't said anything about that you have to find the element. I assumed that you store elements directly into the array, so you don't have to find them. If you don't store elements into this array, you can add an index member to the elements, so you don't have to find them. You don't have to shift elements when removing: you can move the last element into the removed element.

Answer (score 0):

An alternative approach (in my opinion worth only if the number of element is increased at least tenfold) might be keeping a double index:

```
#include<algorithm>
#include<vector>

class didx {
        // v == indexes[i] && v > 0  <==> flagged[v-1] == i
        std::vector<ptrdiff_t> indexes;
        std::vector<ptrdiff_t> flagged;
public:
        didx(size_t size) : indexes(size) {}
        // loop through flagged items using iterators
        auto begin() { return flagged.begin(); }
        auto end() { return flagged.end(); }

        void flag(ptrdiff_t index) {
                if(!isflagged(index)) {
                        flagged.push_back(index);
                        indexes[index] = flagged.size();
                }
        }
        void unflag(ptrdiff_t index) {
                if(isflagged(index)) {
                        // swap last item with item to be removed in "flagged", update indexes accordingly
                        // in "flagged" we swap last element with element at index to be removed
                        auto idx = indexes[index]-1;
                        auto last_element = flagged.back();
                        std::swap(flagged.back(),flagged[idx]);
                        std::swap(indexes[index],indexes[last_element]);

                        // remove the element, which is now last in "flagged"
                        flagged.pop_back();
                        indexes[index] = 0;
                }

        }
        bool isflagged(ptrdiff_t index) {
                return indexes[index] > 0;
        }
};
```

Comment: in this example flag/unflag operations are O(1), looping through flagged elements is O(n), the memory usage is O(N)